# How to output columns in UPDATE statement regardless if row updated

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-update

I have this problem. I need to send 1 SQL query to update the `balance` (keeping with the `WHERE` conditions). I need to know if the row was affected or not. I also ALWAYS need the `last_bal_update` and `balance` column to be outputted to me EVEN IF the row was not updated. Also, we aren't sure if the `customer_id` exists or not. How can I do this.

```
UPDATE person
SET
balance = balance + 20
last_bal_update = '2020-01-01 00:00:00'
WHERE customer_id = 22423412 AND
last_bal_update > '2019-01-01 00:00:00'
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: How do you want to know if the row was affected?

Comment: Well I am using `mysql-connector` which is a mysql python library. So it has a function to check if the row was affected. I am not too stressed about that, so I guess not too important.

Comment: It has a function to tell you how many rows were affected. It doesn't tell you which rows they were.

Comment: Call the function. If it returns 1 then the row was affected, if it returns 0 then the row was not affected.

Comment: @Barmar That is true. Probably as a column in the output to see if it was affected

Comment: `UPDATE` queries don't produce any output, only `SELECT` columns do.

Comment: @Barmar I saw posts where you can use the `OUTPUT`function?

Comment: Are you sure that was MySQL? I've never heard of it.

Comment: @Barmar it was not mysql, I thought I could apply it here somehow.

Comment: Maybe, eventually [mysql](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=83139) / [mariadb](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-12326). But not currently

Comment: Note that LIMIT (even LIMIT 1) is a bit meaningless without an ORDER BY clause